# Getting 'BadRequest' error when provisioning Azure VM (Ubuntu image) with reserved IP via Azure PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, azure

I'm trying to provision a new Azure VM w/ Ubuntu 14.04 server and a reserved IP. I'm using Azure PowerShell for doing this. When everthing's said and done, I end up getting the error: **New-AzureVM : BadRequest: Disktype Linux cannot be used with WindowsProvisioningConfigurationSet.** How do I solve this problem?

---

**Background:** I began via `Add-AzureAccount` and `Set-AzureSubscription`. I then set values for: `$vmName`, `$username`, `$password`, `$location`, `$reservedIP`, `$imageFamily` and `$imageName`.

FYI, `$imageFamily = "Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS"`

and

`$imageName = Get-AzureVMImage | where { $_.ImageFamily -eq $imageFamily } | sort PublishedDate -Descending | select -ExpandProperty ImageName -First 1`

I finally executed `New-AzureVMConfig -Name $vmName -InstanceSize Small -ImageName $imageName | Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows -AdminUsername $username -Password $password | New-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -ReservedIPName $reservedIP -Location $location` and ended up getting the aforementioned error.

Note: If I change `Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows` to `Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux`, I get the error: **parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.**

Answer (score 0):

That Add-AzureVMConfig command is erroneous. The correct command in this case ought to be: `New-AzureVMConfig -Name $vmName -InstanceSize Small -ImageName $imageName | Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux -LinuxUser $username -Password $password | New-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -ReservedIPName $reservedIP -Location $location`

Documentation for this can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495299.aspx